# Stack Exchange app submitting password in cleartext?

Tags: discussion, android-app, security

I have just noticed (by using the Charles web debugging proxy) that the Stack Exchange app is submitting username and password in cleartext at first startup. Isn't that something you shouldn't do, especially because of MITM attacks?

**EDIT:** So it seems like the stackexchange app **is in fact using HTTPS**, but I could phish my password and username string by using an android app called DroidSheep or ANTI and view the password by just being connected to the same network as the target is, so I don't know...

Comment: What do you mean by "submitting username and password in cleartext"? Over HTTP or HTTPS? Also, SO probably isn't the right SE site for this question.

Comment: Over http. Well I thought I to ask here as it is security / programing related? It seems like the password request is made using http and the rest like getting feed using https

Comment: BTW, if it is in fact sending the login credential over HTTP, that sounds bad. I would be interested to see screenshots and other information on that.

Comment: Not at home atm, will post some later

Comment: Are you *sure* it was HTTP? Pretty sure that proxy can generate certs and proxy HTTPS. Try confirming with a separate packet capture (Wireshark/tcpdump).

Comment: What is the HTTPS path of the request?  The only time *we* should be sending a password is when you log in using your SE username/password, and saving the token after that.

Comment: Yes, this does in fact only happen when you first sign in.

Comment: I'm assuming you've installed Charles's SSL certificates on your Android device?

Comment: Yes I did install them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Long story short, the app does not send username/password info in clear text.  When you perform a Stack Exchange login, the app will send your username and password over HTTPS to a Stack Exchange server.  The server then returns an auth token for api.stackexchange.com which is saved on device.  The login credentials are then discarded.

According to the DroidSheep website, [it cannot sniff out HTTPS credentials](http://droidsheep.de/?page_id=424).

What's happening in your case is that you have installed your own root certificate on the device and allowed the proxy to MITM all of your requests.  If you uninstall that certificate your requests will fail due to a certificate error.

It's worth noting that your requests are still not being sent in cleartext unless for some reason Charles is sending them over the network to the display.  Charles receives an encrypted HTTPS request from the app and sends an encrypted HTTPS request to the Stack Exchange server.

Comment: Did you move over to the android app team, or is this the same for both apps? :)